# Chessboard coloring of a knot

Tags: knot-theory

To construct a surface which boundary is a knot we can use the Seifert-algorithm. But we can also make a chessboard coloring of the knotdiagram $D$ of the knot $K$. So we get also an surface with boundary $K$. But why is this construction consistent??

Comment: If you don't know what i mean have a look to the "knotes" van Justin Roberts.

Comment: Is there a link (no pun intended) to these "knotes"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it always gives us a Seifert surface. Check this one.

[image]